# Spark Data frame search column starting with a string

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to filter a data frame based on a condition that a column value should starts with a predefined string.

I am trying following:

```
 val domainConfigJSON = sqlContext.read
    .jdbc(url, "CONFIG", prop)
    .select("DID", "CONF", "KEY").filter("key like 'config.*'")
```

And getting exception:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'KEY = 'config.*'' at line 1

```
Using spark: 1.6.1
```

Comment: `KEY` is also a reserved word in MariaDB.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the `startsWith` function present in Column class.

```
myDataFrame.filter(col("columnName").startswith("PREFIX"))
```

Comment: I had to use `startswith` - all lower-case

Comment: `startsWith`  gives the error _column is not callable_.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same function but I was getting errors then I checked what is the error?

actually, we need to use `startsWith(literals: String)` but the above function having lowercase `startswith()`.

Ex :  `df.filter(col("ACCOUNT_NUMBER").startsWith("9"))`